# Always get previous state in React app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

In relation to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625994/how-to-store-a-state-in-localstorage-for-react), I'm doing this to store the right state:

```
if (value === 'checkpoint')
{
  if (checked1)
  {
    this.setState({checked1 : false})
    localStorage.setObject('checked1', false)
  }
  else
  {
    this.setState({checked1 : true})
    localStorage.setObject('checked1', true)
  }
}
```

Now I have multiple checkboxes (let's say I have four). One for ALL checkboxes, and the other 3 for categories. I want my app to detect when the three category checkboxes are checked, and check the ALL checkbox automatically. When any of the category checkboxes are unchecked, the ALL checkbox will uncheck itself.

I tried this code:

```
  if (checked1 && checked2 && checked3) {
    this.setState({checkedAll: true})
  } else {
    this.setState({checkedAll: false})
  }
```

But the other 3 checkbox (`checked1, checked2, checked3`) will always get a previous state.

How do I get the right state so that my `checkedAll` functions correctly?

Comment: what do you mean when you say they will always get a previous state? Also, in your first codesample: Why do you set the state of checked1 to false when checkd1 is true?

Comment: @ViktorG It's toggle. For checkbox, when you click it on onChange(), u must get an opposite value right?

Comment: Can you post the entire `onChange` handler?

Answer (score 1):

You should rather avoid using `setState()` in `componentDidUpdate()` as it sometimes leads to bugs in your code and is considered not a good practice (e.g. https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-update-set-state.md so if you use airbnb rules to configure your eslint you'll also run into some linting warnings).

Can't you make all four checkboxes controlled inputs like so:

```
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="ch1"
        value="1"
        checked={this.state.ch1}
        onChange={this.onCheckboxChange}
      /> Ch1

      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="ch2"
        value="1"
        checked={this.state.ch2}
        onChange={this.onCheckboxChange}
      /> Ch2

      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="ch3"
        value="1"
        checked={this.state.ch3}
        onChange={this.onCheckboxChange}
      /> Ch3

      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="chall"
        value="1"
        checked={
          this.state.ch1
          && this.state.ch2
          && this.state.ch3
        }
        onChange={this.onCheckboxChange}
      /> Ch all
```

And then in the `onCheckboxChange` (or whatever the name is) just do something like:

```
const { id } = e.target;

if (id === 'chall') {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    this.setState({
      ch1: true,
      ch2: true,
      ch3: true,
    });
    return;
  }

  this.setState({
    ch1: false,
    ch2: false,
    ch3: false,
  });
}

this.setState({
  [id]: e.target.checked,
});
```

Comment: @ThomasRychtyk I do not put the setstate in componentdidupdate. I put it in the onChange() function which run after I click the checkbox.. like what ur answer is.

Comment: I think he's suggesting you not use my answer, which is fair enough although I don't think a blanket rule against `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` is required so long as you cover it with existing state checks as I did. Still, it'll fire an additional render so using controlled components definitely makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more about where in the lifecycle you place this code. `componentDidUpdate` seems like a resonable candidate. For example:

```
componentDidUpdate () {
  const { checked1, checked2, checked3 } = this.state
  const checkedAll = checked1 && checked2 && checked3
  if (checkedAll === this.state.checkedAll) {
    return
  }
  this.setState({ checkedAll })
}
```

In other words, as soon as the boxes all update their state, `checkAll` naturally will too.

Comment: @RichChrucher I put my code in the onChange() function where it will be executed after user press the checkbox

Comment: Yep, that's fine for updating the state of the individual checkboxes. However for `checkedAll` I suggest doing the above, that way it will (eventually) happen *after* your other state changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this.setState({new state}, //perform some action}), whatever action is being performed will receive the most current value of state.

Copy and paste this component and view the console to see it is receiving the correct state

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Menu extends Component {
  state = {
    checkAll: false,
    check1: false,
    check2: false,
    check3: false
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    const all = (this.salmon.checked && this.tuna.checked && this.snapper.checked)
    if (all) {
      this.setState({
        checkAll: true,
        check1: this.salmon.checked,
        check2: this.tuna.checked,
        check3: this.snapper.checked
      }, () => {
        this.all.checked = true
        console.log('Most current state', JSON.stringify(this.state))
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        checkAll: false,
        check1: this.salmon.checked,
        check2: this.tuna.checked,
        check3: this.snapper.checked
      }, () => {
        this.all.checked = false
        console.log('Most current state', JSON.stringify(this.state))
      })
    }
  }

  handleAll = () => {
    this.setState({
      checkAll: true,
      check1: true,
      check2: true,
      check3: true
    }, () => {
      this.salmon.checked = true
      this.tuna.checked = true
      this.snapper.checked = true
      console.log('Most current state', JSON.stringify(this.state))
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Select Options</h1>
        <form>
          <span>
            Select All:
            <input
              onChange={this.handleAll}
              type="checkbox"
              value={this.state.checkAll}
              ref={all => this.all = all}
            />
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                type="checkbox"
                value={this.state.check1}
                ref={salmon => this.salmon = salmon}
              />
              Salmon
            </li>
            <li>
              <input
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                type="checkbox"
                value={this.state.check2}
                ref={tuna => this.tuna = tuna}
              />
              Tuna
            </li>
            <li>
              <input
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                type="checkbox"
                value={this.state.check3}
                ref={snapper => this.snapper = snapper}
              />
              Snapper
            </li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Menu
```

Comment: but for my case is not the matter of callback. It's the matter of detection. I need to detect whether all 3 of the category checkbox is checked. When the detection is using previous state, my checkedAll won't be correct.

Comment: I'll update my answer above, you should be able to copy and paste the component into your code. Since the `callback` takes place after the state is actually set you will receive the values you're looking for rather than the previous state.

Comment: As far as detection `refs` are helpful for getting the DOM value. Notice that the console.log statements when placed inside of a callback actually return the current state which eliminates the need to create an additional variable (referencing your original question). Hope the code above helps.